# shell script (running via cron) to enter password when prompted

Tags: linux, bash, cron, centos, rar

I have a daily cron task which automatically unrars a rar file and processes it's contents, however, the contents are now password protected so i'm wondering if there's a reliable way to echo the password when prompted? The password prompt comes from the UNRAR program i've installed, running on CentOS. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `unrar` for unpacking, you can define the password as command line parameter:

```
unrar x -ppassword package.rar
```

Note that there's no space between `-p` and your `password` parameter.